# Waiting for a promise to be solved to solve another promise in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a nested promises and one promise depends on the result of the other so is it possible to force Angular.js to solve a gien promise before solving the second.

Here is my code:

```
User.getAllUsers().then(function(users) {
    $scope.users = users;
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        console.log('username ' + users[i].username);
        Message.getUnreadMessages(users[i].username, localStorage.getItem("token")).then(function(messages) {
            console.log('username in second promise' + users[i].username);
            $scope.messages.push(messages);
        })
    }
})
```

User and Message are both services. 
The  `console.log('username '+ users[i].username);`displays the correct username.
The `console.log('username in second promise'+ users[i].username);`throws the error`:

> Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Comment: you should consider creating a closure.

Comment: whats a closure can you give me more info ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.getAllUsers().then(function(users) {
    $scope.users = users;
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      (function(user){
        console.log('username ' + user.username);
        Message.getUnreadMessages(user.username, localStorage.getItem("token")).then(function(messages) {
            console.log('username in second promise' + user.username);
            $scope.messages.push(messages);
        })
      })(users[i]);
    }
})
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures, chapter about Closure and loop.

Comment: Thank you it works

Comment: Happy to help you! Can you accept the answer, please?